# What is a Fragment Pipe?

Tags: shaders, fragment-shader

I remember someone saying "24 fragment pipes on nVidia 7800" in a presentation.

Am I correct in saying that a *fragment* is the data that can generate a pixel in the frame buffer? Or are fragments the same thing as pixels? I'm getting confused here.

What *is* a fragment pipe?

Comment: You might ask this in chat, you'd probably get a better discussion about it that way.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "fragment pipe". That's a nonsense term someone made up. It probably references real hardware, but it's not clear what exactly that real hardware is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fragment pipe is a portion of the pixel pipeline that processes fragments. The more you have, the more you can parallelize fragment rendering. More is better, but like many things you get diminishing returns. You can learn more about the graphics pipeline [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter01.html). The pixel pipeline is what's responsible for creating what goes in each pixel on screen, essentially the last two steps of this process:

[image]

So, what's a fragment?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_%28computer_graphics%29):

> In computer graphics, a fragment is the data necessary to generate a
> single pixel's worth of a drawing primitive in the frame buffer.

With a more detailed description also provided:

> As a scene is drawn, drawing primitives (the basic elements of
> graphics output, such as points,lines, circles, text etc.) are
> rasterized into fragments which are textured and combined with the
> existing frame buffer. How a fragment is combined with the data
> already in the frame buffer depends on various settings. In a typical
> case, a fragment may be discarded if it is farther away than the pixel
> that is already at that location (according to the depth buffer). If
> it is nearer than the existing pixel, it may replace what is already
> there, or, if alpha blending is in use, the pixel's color may be
> replaced with a mixture of the fragment's color and the pixel's
> existing color, as in the case of drawing a translucent object.
>
> In
> general, a fragment can be thought of as the data needed to shade the
> pixel, plus the data needed to test whether the fragment survives to
> become a pixel (depth, alpha, stencil, scissor, window ID, etc.)

Comment: Is fragment pipe = Rasterization+Interpolation,Texture,Coloring?

Comment: I'm still not quite understand fragment. Is fragment be the result of Rasterization?

Comment: Yes, the rasterization creates fragments. Then other data is used to fill in the fragment data, then the fragments are combined into pixels and displayed on screen.